# Allow a Job to run if it passes a script

Tags: github-actions

I would like to allow a job to run only if its name can be found in some file.

```
jobs:
  job1:
  if : run some script that returns true if "${{ github.job }}" is in file.txt
  
  steps:
  ...
```

However I'm quite sure i cant run a script outside of run, which I believe can't appear before the steps section, right?

If the option above simply isn't possible, perhaps there is a way to run this script on the first step and have the next steps not run unless the said critical step passed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could for example use 2 jobs in your action, where the second job would only be executed if the first one succeed return `true` using an `if` condition and `outputs`.

The workflow would look like something as below:

```
jobs:
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      output1: ${{ steps.script.outputs.bool }}
    steps:
     - name: Run the python script
       id: script
       run: |
         value=$((your command running the script here) 2> &1) # should return true
         echo "::set-output name=bool::$value" # set the value as output

  job2:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    # Wait from the job1 to be completed before starting job2
    needs: job1
    if ${{ ${{needs.job1.outputs.output1}} == true }} # won't execute if output of job 1 isn't true
    steps:
     ...
```

If you want to know more about:

- [if condition](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idif) + [context and expression](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions)
- [outputs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idoutputs)

***Note**: The [contains expression](https://docs.github.com/pt/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#literals) in the if condition could also be used eventually depending on your context (what the script does). It could even be the easiest solution :)*

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, very helpful, but imagine me having 10 jobs that are supposed to run only if their names are in some txt file. Should I create 10 output variables that will all be initialized by the same script run? Could it be done?

Comment: In that case, it would probably be more interesting to have a script taking care of all scenarios operations, and only execute the script in the workflow. It will also depends on the operation you want to perform (if it's something similar for all jobs, there may be a way to turn it generic in your workflow as well).

Comment: Again, thank you, but could what I suggested be achieved? 
Can I somehow initialize 10 output variables using a return value from a single script run?
Lets say the script returns a boolean array of size 10. Does a syntax exist that could set the 10 output variables to the values of the array?

Comment: It's possible to do it, but it will probably be quite verbose, as you would to have to assign each value of the array using shell command to an output. There may also have some actions on the marketplace that could help (https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions)